# Error importing tensorflow on windows with anaconda navigator

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to import tensorflow and I have already tried everything and in the cmd prompt, I succeeded to install tensorflow with PIP.

[image: command nr 1]

But when I'm trying to import tensorflow in Python, I get the following error:

```
  Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
  you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
  please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python 
  interpreter
  from there.
```

I have tried everything on the internet, but nothing seems to fix it. I have Python version 3.7.1

What is the problem and more important: how can I fix this??

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have already installed tensorflow with pip, trying to install it again with conda is a bad idea.  Before running the conda command, first uninstall the pip version.

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

That is an odd error you are seeing.  Try to specify the channel you are installing from.  It is available from both the anaconda and conda-forge channels

```
conda isntall tensorflow --channel anaconda
```